# Changing content-type while fetching APPLE APP SITE ASSOCIATION in a create react app solution

Tags: react-native, create-react-app, content-type, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to set universal link for an iOS app built with react native. The website version is built with Create React App and is hosted in a simple linux web server. I'm able to create the APPLE APP SITE ASSOCIATION and place it in the root path of the server.

But when I try to download the file by accessing the path, the content type is returning as application/octet-stream. It needs to be downloaded as application/JSON or application/pkcs7-mime for it to be detected as an universal link.

I'm able to find answers on how to set the content type for nginx or apache web server environment, but couldn't find a good solution for a simple Create React App implementation.

Comment: I am also having similar problem. Any solutions for this?

Comment: any solution on this? having the same issue